# Mobclix Ads not showing in subviews

Tags: ios4, mobclix

I have added Mobclix Ads successfully to my app but its showing in first view only and not showing in  subviews . I tried a lot but I am not getting the solution.
If anyone can help me please reply

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the answer by only adding this line to bring subview to front and mobclix ad is showing in every subviews.                      [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.adView];  here adView is the reference of Class MobclixAdView.

Comment: hey @deepti can guide me how did you get the Mobclix ads i am getting trouble to get in my view thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by only adding this line to bring subview to front where another subview is added to view and mobclix ad is showing in every subviews.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.adView];
```

here adView is the reference of Class MobclixAdView.